# Elegant Loop Elsing in Ruby

Tags: ruby, loops

I have to write a Ruby method that:

1. Iterates through an array, doing Foo if one of the elements matches a certain condition.
2. If none of the array elements matched the condition, do Bar  thing.

In any other language, I'd set a Boolean variable before entering the loop and toggle it if I did Foo. The value of that variable would tell me whether I needed to Bar. But that feels unRubyishly inelegant. Can anybody suggest a better way?

**Edit** Some really good answers, but they don't quite work because of a detail I should have mentioned. The something that Foo does is done to the array element that matches the condition. Also, it's guaranteed that at most one element will match the condition.

Comment: You need to show what you've written toward solving this problem. Otherwise it seems like you're fishing for an answer.

Comment: @theTinMan I haven't written anything. It's not a big piece of code in any case. I already know enough to write code that *works* I'm just trying to learn to think like a Ruby person.

Comment: You should accept @Alex Wayne's answer. It addresses the second part of your question.

Comment: @louism Alex's answer has its merits, but I have a better one. Will post it when I have a minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everybody who tried to answer the question. None of you supplied an answer I found appropriate, but you all forced me to think about how you do things the Ruby way (which was the main point of this exercise!) and helped me come up with this answer:

I need to make use of the fact that iterators in Ruby are just methods. All methods return a value, and (oddly enough) `each` returns a *useful* value. If the iteration completes, it returns the collection you were iterating over; if you use `break` to terminate iteration early it returns `nil` (or an optional argument).

So, in a Boolean context, the whole loop is `true` if it completes and `false` if you break out. Thus

```
bar if array.each do |element|
  if fooable(element) then
    foo(element)
    break
  end
end
```

Comment: This is the _opposite_ of what Ruby is about, IMO. I won't mark it down, I just think you should move the tick elsewhere.

Comment: I don't much care whether you mark me down. I *do* care that you don't explain why you want to.

Comment: You have several other answers which display code that is more idiomatic, clearer, uses the library functions the way they were _intended_ (e.g. not relying on the returned value of `each`, or `break` from an iteration where there are other standard functions available), and they work. Yet, you've decided to offer yourself the tick, and you haven't explained why your answer is closer to "the Ruby way", which was apparently the main point, or why their's "weren't appropriate".

Comment: The behavior I used is documented. I agree that my evaluation is subjective, but it's more constructive than your flamebait.

Comment: Everything in Ruby is an expression, but I don't know anyone (except newbies on SO) who uses the return value of `each` because there are other, better and more idiomatic ways to get values back using iterators, that's not flamebait, it's my opinion as someone who writes Ruby regularly and contributes to the community.

Comment: It's not your technical opinions (which do have merit) that makes this flame war. It's your insistence that you understand the "right way" to do things and that I have no right to disagree with you. All the answers on this page are reasonable; I just happen to think mine is the one that best meets the conditions I described. You disagree and I'm sure many others will as well. That's your prerogative; mine, as the person who asked the question is to award the checkmark  as I see fit. If you think my not awarding it the way *you* want me to is a major tragedy, you need to get over yourself.

Comment: In your question you have "unRubyishly inelegant" and in your answer you have "the Ruby way (which was the main point of this exercise!)" so I think I'm in the clear to give my opinion on what is a more or less idiomatic way to write Ruby. No tragedy, just my _valid_ opinion.

Answer (score 6):

Do any of the items match? If yes, then do something, not involving the matching item.

```
if items.any? { |item| item.totally_awesome? }
  foo "we're totally awesome!"
else
  bar "not awesome :("
end
```

Grab the first matching item. If it exists, then do something, with the matching item.

```
awesome_item = items.find { |item| item.totally_awesome? }
if awesome_item
  foo "#{awesome_item.name} is totally awesome!"
else
  bar "no items are awesome :("
end
```

Grab all matching items. If the array has anything in it, then do something with all matching items.

```
awesome_items = items.find_all { |item| item.totally_awesome? }
if awesome_items.any?
  foo "#{awesome_items.size} totally awesome items!"
else
  bar "no items are awesome :("
end
```

Answer (score 5):

You could do it like this:

```
if array.any? { |elem| elem.condition }
  foo
else
  bar
end
```

From the [doc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-any), `Enumerable#any` does the following:

> Passes each element of the collection to the given block. The method returns true if the block ever returns a value other than false or nil.

Answer (score 5):

What you want is [Enumerable#find](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-find)

Ex:

```
element = array.find { |x| x.passes_requirements? }
element ? element.foo! : bar
```

Comment: That's good. It's the one I would have accepted if I hadn't found a way to do it with each.

Comment: This is definitely far better, IMO, than the marked answer, and certainly more idiomatic of good Ruby code.

Comment: "Idiomatic"? Because it uses find instead of each? But that means it needs two steps to do something that each does in one.

Comment: @IsaacRabinovitch It uses [find](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) instead of [each](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-each), yes. Notice how there's no mention of the return value from `each` in the docs but `find` is very clear on it's return values. This is also more concise and easy to read. It could even be done as a one liner `(element = array.find { |x| x.passes_requirements? }) ? element.foo! : bar` and it would still be far better.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: modified based on new question criteria.

```
found_index = nil
my_array.each_with_index.detect { |elem, i| elem.condition? && found_index = i }
if found_index.nil?
  do_not_found_case
else
  my_array[found_index] = some_conversion(elem)
end
```

This isn't as pretty, but it gets the job done and still short-circuits on the first match.

Comment: That's a good answer for the problem the way I stated it, but it doesn't account for a fact I left out: Foo involves changing the array element that matches the condition.

Comment: Trickier.  I can't think of a really short, elegant, Ruby-ish, yet still efficient way to do this.  The more-verbose, but efficient fallback is to flag whether or not a change was made.  I'll edit with a solution but I'd be happy to see a better one.

Comment: @SporkInventor's below is cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

```
idx = the_array.index { |i| conditional(i) }
if idx
  modify_object(the_array[idx])
else
  no_matches
end
```